# How to curry a function in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to curry a function in Vimscript to map an operator. I have a function written in Lua, and I want to pass `'n'` or `'v'` to that function, depending on the mode that trigger that mapping.

```
function! Commented(mode) abort
    let Callback = function("Toggle_commented", [a:mode])
    set opfunc=Callback
    return 'g@'
endfunction

function! Toggle_commented(type) abort
    execute "lua require('commented').toggle_comment()"
endfunction
```

But right now when I run this code, it will return `E117: Unknown function: Callback`. Why is that? how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, `opfunc` requires literal function name not the variable name holding function reference.

If what you want is to simplify opfunc creation there is another way:

```
func! ToggleComment(type = '')
    if a:type == ''
        " HERE you set opfunc to ToggleComment
        let &opfunc = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '[^. ]*$')
        return 'g@'
    endif

    " Do your ToggleCommenting stuff here
    " execute "lua require('commented').toggle_comment()"
endfunc

nnoremap <silent> <expr> <space>c ToggleComment()
```

Check `let &opfunc = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '[^. ]*$')` line.
Here `expand('<sfile>')` would be `function ToggleComment` and with matchstr you extract function name.

Here for example my operator for vimscript evaluation:

```
" Essential for my vimscripting
" run selected vimscript
xnoremap <silent> <space>v y:@"<cr>
" run vimscript line
nmap <space>vv V<space>v

" run operator
func! s:vimrun(type = '')
    if a:type == ''
        let &opfunc = matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '[^. ]*$')
        return 'g@'
    endif
    let commands = #{line: "'[V']y", char: "`[v`]y", block: "`[\<c-v>`]y"}
    silent exe "noautocmd keepjumps normal! " .. get(commands, a:type, '')
    @"
endfunc
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <space>v <SID>vimrun()
```

With `<space>vip` I can evaluate paragraph as vimscript...